# How to set basepath for specified fields in query_string?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

In next query:

```
  const paramQueryString = JSON.stringify(queryString);

next:

            "query_string": {
              "query": ${paramQueryString},
              "fields": ["searchable.*"],
              "lenient": true,
              "default_operator": "and",
              "analyze_wildcard": true,
              "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
              "type" : "cross_fields"
            }
```

I want to be able set `queryString` to `name: xxx city: yyy`.

I want it looks for: `searchable.name: xxx searchable.city: yyy`.
Is there a safe way to do this?
Can I somehow specify basepath for fields?

Or any other solution. I have access to mapping / document storage time.

Thank you in advance

I right now I need to specify in `queryString` complete fields path: `searchable.name: xxx searchable.city: yyy` to achieve desired result.

Or: `\\*.name: xxx \\*.city: yyy`